# Dropping empty facets from ggplot and labeling independently

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some fairly simple data, e.g.,

```
library(dplyr)
dat <-
  data.frame(species = sample(c("1", "2"), 200, TRUE), 
           psd = sample(c("s", "q", "p", "m", "t"), 200, TRUE), 
           val = sample(40:120, 200, TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(pop = ifelse(species == "1", 
                      sample(c("a", "b", "f"), length(species), TRUE), 
                      sample(c("c", "d", "e", "g"), length(species), TRUE)))
```

`pop` between species are mutually exclusive.

I'd like to plot these data one one plot, e.g.,

```
dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = psd, y = val)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA) +
  facet_grid(species~pop, drop = T)
```

[image]

but there are empty facets (e.g., `species == "2"` & `pop = "c"`). Can these empty facets be dropped somehow and each facet labelled individually?

Comment: `facet_wrap(species~pop, drop = TRUE, scales = "free")`

Comment: If you want it in a grid layout I think you can't drop those empty facets. For example while `pop = "c"` only has `species = 2`, it needs an empty facet for `species = 1` to maintain the grid layout. You should try `facet_wrap` instead.

Comment: @d.b yes, this is easy to do, but I'd like to maintain the "look" of the `facet_grid()`, specfically, each species named at the end of the row. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p1 = dat[dat$species == 1,] %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = psd, y = val)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA) +
    facet_grid(species~pop)

p2 = dat[dat$species == 2,] %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = psd, y = val)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA) +
    facet_grid(species~pop)

library(grid)
library(egg)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: This was where I was going thinking I'd have to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- mutate(dat, Name <- paste(species, pop, sep = ""))
dat %>%
ggplot(aes(x = psd, y = val)) +
       geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA) +
       facet_grid(. ~ Name)
```

Fiddle with the paste command to further customize your labels, but this example would give `c("1a", "1b", "2c", "2d", "2e", "1f", "2g")` as your names